# Raspberrypi 4 can't get the data from gps module

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpsd

I'm currently missing with GPS configuration and didn't know where is the problems, please if someone have an idea to share with me the solution,

I'm using Raspberrypi 4 Model B 4GB RAM and a sim808 GPS module,
[Sim808 GPS module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soy7N.jpg)

I did TX pin to RX, RX to TX pin, VCC to 5V, ground to ground.

also I did those configuration:

sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt :
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait

sudo nano /boot/config.txt :
[/boot/config.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68cLh.jpg)

sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd :
[etc/default/gpsd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf9kV.jpg)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuhdx.jpg)

Please help!